# How to attach event listener on each list item in Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component like this:

```
  Vue.component('navbar', {
  props: ['navitem'],
  methods: {
    users: function () {
        //users code
    },

    test:function(){
    }
  },
  template: '<li v-on:click="navitem.name"> {{navitem.name}} </li>'
  });
```

and i want to pass the following array to the component:

```
navitems: [{ id: 1, name: 'users' }, { id: 2, name: 'test' }]
```

and render them like this:
      *v-for="item in navitems" v-bind:navitem="item" :key="item.id"*

such that each list item get the corresponding event listener,
that is the end rendered list items will be like this:

```
  <li v-on:click="users()"></li> 
  <li v-on:click="test()"></li>
```

how this can be done if possible?

Comment: You need the component `navbar` to handle the `li` click event or the parent component that wraps the `navbar` to listen to this event?

Comment: Yes i need the navbar to handle event listener for each list item.

Comment: Why not passing a value to your handler method which then would designate the needed behavior?

Comment: Then just declare a method in `methods:{}` like ex: `listClicked:function(){}` and pass that to `v-on:click="listClicked"` . Inside this method you will have access to the prop `navitem`

Comment: i want this component to be really compact such that the end rendered list items will be like this:
    <li v-on:click="users()"></li>
    <li v-on:click="test()"></li>
i hope this will clarify the problem little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that you are passing a string to the component, not a function reference. To call the function, simply "select" the function from the component by looking it up in the component object, then calling it.

```
Vue.component('navbar', {
  props: ['navitem'],
  methods: {
    users: function () {
        //users code
    },

    test:function(){
    },

    clickHandler(name) {
      this[name]();
    }
  },
  template: '<li v-on:click="clickHandler(navitem.name)"> {{navitem.name}} </li>'
});
```

Comment: Thank you Sumurai8 that is exactly what i wanted.